# where to place indeterminate pronouns/determiners/adverbs in a sentence like "we've all been studying"

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, determiners, syntax

In the sentence "we've also all been studying" are the "also" (in Spanish is categorized as adverb of affirmation) and "all" (in Spanish is categorized as indeterminate pronoun or determinant) being placed correctly? . I like to know when I have to construct sentences with these types of words (they might have another category in English) how to grammatically construct them right and also in the case they are right if that's the best choice for them to sound natural.

Comment: You really should abandon comparisons with Spanish; they won't help you learn English, and may even impede your progress. When you say "they may have another category in English", you seem to tell us that you haven't consulted your dictionary. What does your English language dictionary tell you about the adverb _"also"_ and the pronoun _"all"_? Are there example sentences in your dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to abandon comparisions because they indeed help learning languages. I dont know why you think otherwise. Do you have the experience of learning other languages?

Comment: Why do you want to put *also* between *we've* and *all*? The main phrase "we've all been studying" is fine. Then, what is the additional activity that *also* refers to? In short, *also* should be outside the main phrase. "Also we've all been studying" is more natural.

Comment: Alors, mais certainment! That was advice, and of course you're free to reject it if you like. Comparisons with a native language may be helpful in the beginning, but they can introduce confusion as a student progresses. This is particularly true when the student's native language is a Romance language that is highly inflected, and when the language being studied is English, which is hardly inflected at all. (_"We've all been studying, too"_ is the way the sentence would be spoken in idiomatic English. _"Also"_ is a poor fit here because it repeats _all_, which is a component of _"all so"_.)